# What type of value do overloaded operators return (for user-defined types): rvalue or lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

I was reading Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs by Scott Meyers and he stated:

> Having a function return a constant value is generally inappropriate, but sometimes doing so can reduce the incidence of client errors without giving up safety or efficiency. For example, consider the declaration of the operator* function:

```
class Rational { ... };

const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
```

According to Meyers, do this prevents "atrocities" like this, which would be illegal if a, b were primitive types:

```
Rational a, b, c;

...

(a * b) = c;
```

This got me confused and while trying to understand why the above assignment was illegal for primitive types but not user-defined types, I came across rvalues and lvalues

I still feel I don't have a strong grasp of what rvalues and lvalues are after looking through some SO questions, but here's my basic understanding: an lvalue references a location in memory and thus can be assigned to (it can be on both sides of = operator as well); an rvalue however, cannot be assigned to because it does not reference a memory location(e.g. temporary values from function returns and literals)

My question is: why is assigning to a product of two numbers/objects legal for user-defined types (even though it does not make sense) but not primitives? Does it have to do with return types? does the overloaded * operator return an assignable value or a temporary value?

Comment: If you return by value (like your operator function does) then making that returned value `const` is irrelevant. If the returned value is used as a source for assignment (like e.g. `c = a * b`) then the code can assign the value to a non-constant variable anyway. And if you have the temporary value be the target of an assignment (as in `a * b = c` from your example) the assignment of the temporary object will be lost anyway. `const` only makes sense if you return a *reference*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so `a * b = c` returns a temporary object of the left? Why then does the compiler not complain about this like it does for primitive types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [`[expr.call]/14:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#14) A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

This makes sense, since the result doesn't "have a name". If you returned a reference, the implication would be that it is a reference to some object somewhere that *does* "have a name" (which is, generally but not always, true).

Then there's this:

> [`[expr.ass]/1:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1) The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand; their result is an lvalue referring to the left operand.

This is saying that an assignment requires an lvalue on the left hand side. So far so good; you've covered this yourself.

How come a non-`const` function call result works then?

By a special rule!

> [`[over.oper]/8:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#8): *[..]* Some predefined operators, such as +=, require an operand to be an lvalue when applied to basic types; this is not required by operator functions.

… and `=` applied to an object of class type invokes an operator *function*.

I can't readily answer the "why": on the surface of it, it made sense to relax this restriction when dealing with classes, and the original (inherited) restriction on built-ins always seemed a little excessive (in my opinion) but would have had to be kept for compatibility reasons.

But then you have people like Meyers pointing out that it now becomes *useful* (sort of) to return `const` values to effectively "undo" this change.

Ultimately I wouldn't try too hard to find a strong rationale either way.

Comment: A more modern way of achieving this would to reference qualify assignment (`T& T::operator=(const T&) &;`)

Comment: @Caleth Yeah true

Comment: @Caleth Is this similar to the const qualifier? I mean, is this to guarantee that the operator returns a reference?

Comment: @IbrahimSuleiman the `&` on the end acts analogously to `const` in the same position (and they can be combined). It means it can only be *called* on an lvalue `T` (i.e. not `(a * b)`)

Comment: It gives you the same (ish) result using a different (and more appropriate) mechanism.